# Flexbox header that when on mobile becomes a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a website using flexbox for the header. However, it breaks on mobile devices so I wanted to know if there was a way to make the 3 links on the right (look at the code to understand) collapse into a burger-menu style dropdown if the width of the browser means it wouldn't all fit on one row.

### Code

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/overfront64/pen/XWKJyyd)

#### HTML

```
<header>
  <!--Random placeholder logo-->
    <img id="logo" src="https://www.goomlandscapes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/logo-placeholder.png" alt="Logo" />
    <nav class="nav_links">
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
</header>
```

#### CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

* {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252a;
    color: #edf0f1;
}

li, a, button {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 25px 7%;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
}

#logo {
    height: 36px;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: You may find this section in W3Schools on responsive design helpful as well: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query to specify at what browser width you want your menu to turn into hamburger style. Proper syntax looks like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    some-property: value;
  }
}
```

This will alter the way your nav element is styled whenever the browser width becomes smaller than 768px.